# Format Exception with Convert.ToDecimal

Tags: c#, exception, format, try-catch

I keep getting back my own catch statement which is "Invalid numeric format. Please check all entries." when I type in "S" as the Employee Type, "30" for Hours Worked, and "200" for Sales Revenue. I have to calculate the commission and total pay based off the employee type and the data entered under Hours Worked and Sales Revenue. I have been trying to figure this out forever and I don't know why it's happening. I understand that it is a format exception but I'm not understanding why it's giving me this error. It obviously has something to do with the first three variables when I type in the data in the text boxes when running the form. Please help!

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string employeeType = txtEmployeeType.Text;
            decimal hours = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHoursWorked.Text);
            decimal revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesRevenue.Text);
            decimal commission = Decimal.Parse(txtSalesCommission.Text);
            decimal totalPay = Decimal.Parse(txtTotalPay.Text);

            txtSalesRevenue.Text = revenue.ToString("c");
            txtSalesCommission.Text = commission.ToString("c");
            txtTotalPay.Text = totalPay.ToString("c");

            //Employee Types: S   = Salaried Employees
            //                HC  = Hourly Commission Employees
            //                HNC = Hourly Non-Commission Employees  

            if (employeeType == "S")

            {
                totalPay = (300 + commission);
                commission = (revenue * .02m);
            }

            else if (employeeType == "HC")

            {
                totalPay = ((12 * hours) + commission);
                commission = (revenue * .01m);
            }

            else if (employeeType == "HNC")
            {
                totalPay = (16 * hours);
                commission = (revenue * 0);
            }
        }

        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Invalid numeric format. Please check all entries.",
                "Entry Error");
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Overflow error. Please enter smaller values.",
                "Entry Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                ex.Message,
                ex.GetType().ToString());                               
        }
        txtTotalPay.Focus();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: search for decimal.TryParse

Comment: why would I do tryparse when I already have a try-catch statement? I've really only learned try catch statements. Or would it matter if I put a try catch statement on each employee type?

Comment: You have invalid values in txtSalesCommission.Text or txtTotalPay.Text, which cannot be converted to decimal.

Comment: But I don't enter anything into those fields. They are supposed to be calculated from the first 3 fields of employee type, hours worked, and sales revenue. And I get the catch statement when I hit calculate because the values that i put into those first 3 fields are invalid and I dont know why or how.

Comment: so If you assign a non compatible value to a decimal, what do you expect?  Tell me what are values of txtSalesCommission.Text or txtTotalPay.Text after your calculation

Comment: I can't get the calculation of sales commission or total pay since I'm getting the catch statement with a format exception which im imagining is from the first 3 fields.

Comment: In which line you are getting exception?

Comment: It's not an actual exception for a line where it tells me. I'm getting my own try-catch statement message box back when I hit calculate which is the format exception catch.

Comment: use breakpoint, and run your code by pressing f10.line by line

Comment: well I did that and I put a breakpoint on the decimal totalpay line and pressed f10 on the decimal commission line and it brought up program.cs and shows an "InvalidOperationException was unhandled" error with "Additional information: SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application." so what is going on then?

Comment: it points the error to "Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);"